# Expected Cost of Picking Up Same Colored Ball

Tags: probability

Assuming there are 10 Colored Ball $$\{ A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J \}$$

My goal is to get two balls of color "$J$", by picking it from a bag one at a time. (You will replace the ball each time you pick).

But there is a condition,

1. Cost of picking a ball is $230 \ 769$ dollars
2. As soon as you pick the ball of another color, you have to pay a fine of $200 \ 000$ dollars. And you cannot continue the game, you have to restart.

I cannot get the mathematical formula to represent the expected cost.

For some reason, simple table manage to arrive at the answer too!
[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn't use A and B for both colors and dollars.

Comment: @BrianTung, thanks i have editted!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the only way you can win is to get $J$ twice in a row.

So in the first round, you either

- Pay $\$230769$ and get $J$ with $p=\frac1{10}$, then continue to the next round, or
- Pay $\$430769$ and not get $J$ with $p=\frac9{10}$ and restart.

The next round has the same outcome as above. Hence, the moment you get two $J$'s you end the game, otherwise, you keep spending $E$, where $E$ is the expected cost.

Mathematically,
$$E=\underbrace{\frac{1}{10}}_\text{first round $J$, continue}\left(230769+\underbrace{\frac{1}{10}(230769)}_\text{second round $J$, end}+\underbrace{\frac{9}{10}(E+430769)}_\text{second round not $J$, restart}\right)+\underbrace{\frac{9}{10}(E+430769)}_\text{first round not $J$, restart}$$
which you can then solve to get
$$E\approx4.51846\times10^7$$

---

I suppose that your numbers are made up so if the cost of drawing a ball is $x$ and the fine is $y$, with $x,y>0$, then

$$E={\frac{1}{10}}\left(x+\frac{1}{10}x+{\frac{9}{10}(E+x+y)}\right)+\frac{9}{10}(E+x+y)$$
which solves to
$$E=110x+99y$$

Comment: Thank you! What does 456389 really mean? I ran a brute force simulation and it seems to say that i need approx 45 million dollars to expect to win.

Comment: @Zanko so sorry I made some typo! I’m fixing it now

Comment: @zanko alright it’s fixed!

Comment: thank you so much the answer is really beautiful! I manage to get the same answer by doing simple table (I uploaded as part of the question). Do you mind explaining why it works? Also, for you answer where do geometric series come into play? Thanks!

Comment: @Zanko yep in fact the table works too but we generally avoid it because the risk of miscounting in more complicated cases. For this particular problem, geometric distribution works too but you will have to divide the cases up first which imo, is less efficient.

Comment: @Zanko I’m on my phone right now. I’ll add more alternative methods once I reach home.