# On average, how much money do I expect to have to spend to "theoretically" have to win the game?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Game is very simple, a bag with 3 balls `{Red, Blue, Green}`

You play by picking the ball with equal probability.

If you did not get Red, you need to pay a fine of 20,000.

If you get Red the game stop and you win. (You only care about winning)

How much money do you need to have in order to win the game?

I ran a basic simulation

```
let winSoFar = 0;
let numberOfSimulation = 1000000;
let totalFine = 0;
while (winSoFar < numberOfSimulation) {
  while (true) {
    const number = random.from(1,2,3);
    if (number !== 3) {
      totalFine+=20000;
    } else {
      winSoFar++;
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(totalFine/numberOfSimulation);
```

It always give me around 40,000. I wonder how to get this mathematically? Is this the same as the term **expected cost**?

Comment: You will need an infinite amount of money in order to win the game since you can always keep getting blue or green until you are out of cash.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat hi i see where you are coming from. But on the other hand, someone will get extremely lucky and win on first try. Averaging these result is where the simulation get 40000.

Comment: When you say "averaging", then this means you are looking for expected values. I.e. how much money do you _expect to have to spend_ to win the game. Is this how you meant to phrase the question? This is very different to "how much money do I have to spend to win the game", because that would suggest you want a result which is certain. But in the game you have described, nothing is certain.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes is think so, ill rephrase the question. In any case, the simulation give me 40000, I can't seem to get the actual formula mathematically. Also is this the same thing as "expected cost"?

Comment: You need $3$ tries in the average to get red, so you will lose two times the fine in the average. And what do you mean with "extremely lucky" ? To win on the first try, you only need to hit a $1:3$-chance.

Comment: @Zanko please see my answer where I explained in more details

Comment: @Zanko yes, it is the same as expected cost.

Comment: Maybe an off-topic question, but how did you get the idea for such a "game" with an astronomical fine and apparently no chances to win anything but the game ? Just for curiousity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denotes the number of rounds needed to win the game.

We know that
$$P(X=r)=(1-p)^{r-1}p$$ i.e.$$X\sim\mathrm{Geo}(p)$$
where $p$ is the probability of winning a particular round, in this case, the probability of getting red. That is,
$$p=\frac13$$
The expected number of rounds needed is $$E(X)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty{rP(X=r)}=\frac1p=3$$
Hence, you are *expected* to lose $2$ rounds, and are *expected* to need 
$$ $40000$$
initially to win.

**BUT**  in order to **SURELY** win the game you will need an infinite amount of money since there is no finite number of rounds where you will definitely win within.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind answer this one too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758401/expected-cost-of-picking-up-same-colored-ball?noredirect=1#comment5689747_2758401? I am having trouble applying the geometric distribution for dependant case

Answer (score 0):

The event of you winning this game follows a geometric distribution - either you pick the red ball (with prob $1/3$) and **win**, losing no money, or you don't and you **lose**, costing you $20,000$.

The expectation of a geometric distribution with probability $p$ is $1/p$. So here, you are expected to have to play $\frac1{1/3}=3$ times, where you win on the third try. So you lost twice, therefore spent $40,000$.